# Auth::user() not defined in Laravel Route Group

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm trying to get auth users data and use it for creating sub-domain.

I found, that I can get need data at single route, such:

```
Route::get('/', function ()
    if (Auth::user()) {
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
    return view('user.login');
});
```

But I can't get data in group ruotes. Such I get null:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
    $id = Auth::id();
    Route::any($id.'/', 'myController@myAction')->name('some');
```

Comment: I'd put that logic inside of a controller instead of the route.

Answer (score 1):

```php
Route::get('/', function ()
    if (Auth::user()) {
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
    return view('user.login');
});
```

It works cause the function is in the same position as a controller in the lifespan of the request. At that sequence, the `AuthServiceProvider`has already finished booting.

In the second one, The callback function is part of the routing provider, wich is triggered before assigning the `Auth::user()`.

What you should do, since it's a route for logged in user only, is to have it static

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
    $id = Auth::id();
    Route::any('/', 'myController@myAction')->name('some');
```

or

```php
    Route::any('profile', 'myController@myAction')->name('some');
```

And in your controller, you can recover the `id`

`MyConrtoller.php`

```php
public function myAction()
{
    $id = \Auth::id();
}
```

Comment: And how can I get `id` in routes, if controller return data to view?

Comment: you get the `id` in the controller not in the route cause of the bootstrapping procedure.